# Puppet cron job -- ensure files exist

Tags: cron, puppet, puppet-enterprise

I'm trying to set up a Puppet cron job with the following structure:

```
file { '/usr/local/sbin/file.py':
  mode    => '0755',
  source  => 'puppet:///modules/file.py',
  require => File['/usr/local/sbin']
}

cron { "cronjob":
  require => "ALL_THE_FILES_ABOVE"
  command => "...command_to_run_script..."
  minute => '*/1'
}
```

All of the above is in one file `run_script.pp`. I'm wondering how I can code the `require => "ALL_THE_FILES_ABOVE"` part.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Based on the information provided in your question, I am going to make the assumption that the contents of `run_script.pp` is many `file` resources and the listed `cron` resource. You state that you want the `cron` resource there to require all of the `file` resources in that class. Based on this, here is a clean and efficient solution.

There are a few complicated/advanced ways to arrive at a clean and efficient solution, but the easiest to understand is to use a resource default: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/lang_defaults.html

With this, we can establish attribute/value pair defaults for all `file` resources contained in that scope. This would make it easier to use the `before` metaparameter on the `file` resources instead: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/metaparameter.html#before

This simplifies the solution to a one-liner in your class:
`File { before => Cron['cronjob'] }`

Note there will be a caveat to this method, which is that if you are declaring, requiring, or containing a class within this manifest, then this default could be expanded to that "area of effect" and cause a circular dependency. In that case, you should use a per-expression resource default attribute: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/lang_resources_advanced.html#per-expression-default-attributes

Answer (score 0):

You can use a multiple require

```
file{'path/foo':}
file{'path/bar':}
file{'~/foobar':
  require => [ File['path/foo'], File['path/bar'] ]
}
```

or you can use the ordering arrow

> -> (ordering arrow; a hyphen and a greater-than sign) — Applies the resource on the left before the resource on the right.

```
 file{'path/foo':} ->
   file{'path/bar':} ->
   file{'~/foobar':}
```

Here is more information about [**relationships and ordering**](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/4.9/lang_relationships.html) in Puppet